# Can I have a user-defined error message next to a restplus model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restplus

I have written a `Flask` application that provides an API. I am using the `RESTplus` library.

I use a model to format the data. If a request is successful, the values are inserted into the model and the model is returned.
However, if the request is unsuccessful, the model is returned and all values are `null`. My goal is to return a user-defined error message with multiple key-value pairs. The error message should have a different structure than as Model.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, fields, Api


app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api()
api.init_app(app)


books = {'1': {"id": 1, "title": "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns", 'author': "Addy Osmani"},
         '2': {"id": 2, "title": "Speaking JavaScript", "author": "Axel Rauschmayer"}}

book_model = api.model('Book', {
    'id': fields.String(),
    'title': fields.String(),
    'author': fields.String(),
})

@api.route('/books/<id>')
class ApiBook(Resource):

    @api.marshal_with(book_model)
    def get(self, id):
        try:
            return books[id]
        except KeyError as e:
            return {'message': 'Id does not exist'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Successful output**

`curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/books/1" -H "accept: application/json"`

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns",
  "author": "Addy Osmani"
}
```

**Erroneous output**

`curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/books/3" -H "accept: application/json"`

```
{
  "id": null,
  "title": null,
  "author": null
}
```

Is it possible to have a user-defined error message next to a model? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't catch the exception in the `get` method and then return an object; anything you *return* from the method will be marshalled using the model.

Instead, follow the [error handling documentation](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors.html) and use `flask.abort()` to set a `404` response with message:

```
# at the top of your module
from flask import abort

# in the resource class
@api.marshal_with(book_model)
def get(self, id):
    try:
        return books[id]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise abort(404, 'Id does not exist')
```

The second argument you give `abort()` is automatically turned into a JSON object with `message` key, so `{"message": "Id does not exist"}`.

You could also create a `@api.errorhandler` registration for the `KeyError` exception and turn that into a 404 response:

```
@api.errorhandler(KeyError)
def handle_keyerror(error):
    return {"message": f"Object with id {error} could not be found"}, 404
```

and then *don't catch the exception in your `get()` methods*:

```
@api.marshal_with(book_model)
def get(self, id):
    return books[id]
```

Note that when `ERROR_404_HELP` is set to `True` (the default) then the message is added to by RestPlus with an alternative route suggestion, tacked on to every 404 response:

```sh
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/books/3" -H "accept: application/json"
{
    "message": "Object with id '3' could not be found. You have requested this URI [/books/3] but did you mean /books/<id> ?"
}
```

This may not be that helpful in your specific case so you may want to disable `ERROR_404_HELP`.